# What are the components of this Golang Function Declaration?

Tags: go

I'm confused by the structure of the following Golang code:

```
type Team []*athlete

func (s Team) Len() int {
    //some code here
}

func (s Team) Swap(i, j int) {
    s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
}
```

I'm new to go and not familiar with this function declaration structure. What are the input/output values? Apologies for what I'm sure is a naive question. Tried to google, referenced my Go book, and still confused.

Comment: Have you walked through the [Tour Of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1)?

Comment: What are the input/output values? i and j?

Comment: Thanks @JimB, found the answer in Tour of Go.

Answer (score 4):

In the declaration `func (r Thing) Name(variable aType) otherType`, the various things are (in order):

- `func` is the "this is a function" keyword
- `(r Thing)` indicates "this is a method on the type `Thing`, the value the method is invoked on will be in the variable `r`" (normal functions do not have a receiver; methods always have exactly one receiver).
- `Name` is the name of the method
- `(variable aType)` is an argument list, in this case a single argument, of the type `aType`. It is perfectly valid to have zero arguments to a method.
- `otherType` is the return type, this can be omitted, if no useful return value exists.